# How can I Convert Eastern Standard Date Time to Utc using moment js?

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

How can I Convert Eastern Standard  Date Time to Utc using moment js while my browser time will remain the Pakistan Standard Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [tz()](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) function to create a date in Eastern Standard Time.

You can then use .`utc()` to convert this to UTC.

If you want another timezone (say Pakistan) you can use .tz() again to convert:

```js
// Our input time (in Eastern Standard Time).
const inputTime = '2021-09-03 04:45:00';

// Create our moment object in Eastern Standard Time
const easternTime = moment.tz(inputTime, 'EST');
console.log('Times:')
console.log('Eastern: ', easternTime.format());

// Now use .utc() to convert to utc timezone.
const utcTime = easternTime.utc();
console.log('UTC:     ', utcTime.format());

// Now use .tz() to convert to Pakistan Standard Time.
const pakistanTime = utcTime.tz('Asia/Karachi');
console.log('Pakistan:', pakistanTime.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```